# Is there a difference between self.current_user and @current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking at this ruby code and they make reference to:

```
@current_user
```

and

```
self.current_user
```

what is the difference?

http://code.google.com/p/openplaques/source/browse/trunk/www/lib/authenticated_system.rb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@current_user` is an [instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html).  `self.current_user` calls the method on line 10 that returns that instance variable, first populating it if it is currently nil.

Answer (score 4):

`@current_user` accesses the actual property of the object whereas `self.current_user` is calling the `current_user` method on `self`.

This means you could do something like this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user.first_name
end
```

So now accessing `@current_user` will still give you the property but `self.current_user` will give you back the first name only.

In your specific example they are using object caching to set the `@current_user` property only the first time it is accessed. This means that if `@current_user` is nil, it'll do `(login_from_session || login_from_basic_auth || login_from_cookie)` otherwise it'll just return the existing object without reinitializing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@current_user
```

dereferences the instance variable called `@current_user`.

```
self.current_user
```

sends the message `:current_user` to `self`.